# PySpark Join with Key in simple way

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark

Here I have two table teacher and student, I want to Join these table with Teacher ID ( A,B,C,D) . I have the solution as well. My question is, **Is there any other way on Getting the same result , like a simple join etc**. as Join works in Key value pair.

```
"""
My Input 
    teacher
    A,Alpha
    B,Bravo
    C,Charlie
    D,Delta

    student
    1,A,Aadarsh
    2,c,Sun
    3,B,Aagam
    4,A,Aadidev
    5,B,Ideal
    6,B,Aaditya
    7,B,Supreme
    8,A,Arrival
    9,c,Aahan

    """
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    sc = SparkContext()

    def stu(st):
        line = st.split(",")
        stId = line[0]
        stTId = line[1]
        stName = line[2]
        return (stTId,stId,stName)
    def tea(te): 
        line = te.split(",")
        teId = line[0]
        teName = line[1]
        return (teId,teName)

    getStu = student.map(lambda x : stu(x))
    getTea = teacher.map(lambda y : tea(y))
    joinStuTea = getTea.map(lambda x : (x[0],x[1])).join(getStu.map(lambda x : (x[0],(x[1],x[2]))))
    formatData = joinStuTea.map(lambda (x1,(x2,(k,v))) : k + " " + x1 + " " + x2 + " " +  v)  
    for x in formatData.collect():
        print x
```

**Result**

```
1 A Alpha Aadarsh
4 A Alpha Aadidev
8 A Alpha Arrival
2 C Charlie Sun
9 C Charlie Aahan
3 B Bravo Aagam
5 B Bravo Ideal
6 B Bravo Aaditya
7 B Bravo Supreme
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dataframes.

First let's convert your RDD `student`, `teacher` into dataframes:

```
stu_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    student.map(lambda l: l.split(",")), 
    ["stId", "teId", "stName"]
)
teacher_df = spark.createDataFrame(
    teacher.map(lambda l: l.split(",")), 
    ["teId", "teName"]
)
```

Now to join them

```
df = stu_df.join(teacher_df, "teId", "inner")

    +----+----+-------+-------+
    |teId|stId| stName| teName|
    +----+----+-------+-------+
    |   B|   5|  Ideal|  Bravo|
    |   B|   3|  Aagam|  Bravo|
    |   B|   6|Aaditya|  Bravo|
    |   B|   7|Supreme|  Bravo|
    |   C|   2|    Sun|Charlie|
    |   C|   9|  Aahan|Charlie|
    |   A|   1|Aadarsh|  Alpha|
    |   A|   4|Aadidev|  Alpha|
    |   A|   8|Arrival|  Alpha|
    +----+----+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Just curious to ask , if I am not using dataframe , whether my approach, which I mentioned above is a good one to proceed?

Comment: dataframes are a lot faster than RDDs